# React routing - Keeping props within the same view

Tags: reactjs

I currently have a few routing paths in my code which pass in a number of properties to those views. As below:

```
import React, {Component}  from 'react'
import { Route, Switch, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import CalendarView from '../calendarView'
import ListView from '../listView'
import AgendaView from '../agendaView'
import propTypes from 'prop-types'


class DiaryRouting extends Component{
  render() {
    const activities = this.props.activities
    return (
        <switch>
          <Route exact path="/my-diary/"  render={() => <Redirect push to="/my-diary/activities/calendar-view/month" component={(props) => <CalendarView {...props} selectedViewRange = 'calendar-view' selectedViewType='month' selectedDiaryType='activities' activities={activities}/>}  /> } />
          <Route exact path="/my-diary/activities/"   render={() => <Redirect push to="/my-diary/activities/calendar-view/month" component={(props) => <CalendarView {...props} selectedViewRange = 'calendar-view' selectedViewType='month' selectedDiaryType='activities' activities={activities}/>}  /> } />
          <Route exact path="/my-diary/jobs/"         render={() => <Redirect push to="/my-diary/jobs/calendar-view/month" component={(props) => <CalendarView {...props} selectedViewRange = 'calendar-view' selectedViewType='month' selectedDiaryType='jobs' activities={activities}/>}  /> } />
      </switch>
    )
  }
}

DiaryRouting.propTypes = {
  activities: propTypes.array,
}

export default DiaryRouting
```

I have items being passed in such as selectedViewRange  and selectedDiaryType into each route. What I am trying to accomplish to having a variable in this view that holds what route it has gone through and what variable has been passed in. Such as below:

```
    ....
    state = {
      selectedViewRange: null
    }

    ... <Route exact path="/my-diary/activities/"  
 render={() => <Redirect push to="/my-diary/activities/calendar-view/month" 
component={(props) => this.setState(selectedViewRange: 'calendar-view') <CalendarView {...props} selectedViewRange = 'calendar-view' selectedViewType='month' selectedDiaryType='activities' activities={activities}/>}  /> } />
```

However I keep getting a

> Warning: setState(…): Cannot update during an existing state
>   transition

I have tried using a variable instead of a state and that does not do anything.

Best approach how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd strongly suggest to use `redux` for  app state management because `setState` has never been a reliable and scaleable choice.

Anyways, to answer your question:

For the class component that holds your `state` for `activeRoute` (rephased your `selectedViewRange` for better understanding), you should define a method like:

`setActiveRoute = (activeRoute) => { this.setState({ activeRoute }) }`

Pass it as a prop to the components that you render in your routes.

So basically, your `CalendarView` should have an extra prop like `setActiveRouteName` and you should pass `this.setActiveRoute` as a callback to `setActiveRouteName` prop like:

`<CalendarView {...props} setActiveRouteName={this.setActiveRoute} ... />`

Moving on, in your `CalendarView`, declare a React lifecycle method `componentDidMount`. It should look like:

```
export default class CalendarView extends Component {
   componentDidMount(){
     this.props.setActiveRouteName('yourRouteName');
   }

   ...other code...
}
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: This half works, it sets the state but is constantly fired off rather than setting the state only once. Any reason why?.